# Blogger: html search with parameters

Tags: html, blogger

i have a problem, i create template in blogger and there to search for text with a label need this url:

> www.my_blog.blogspot.com/search?q=label:Printers+SearchText

I have this code:

```html
<form action='/search' class='search' method='GET'>
 <input name='q' placeholder='Пошук' type='text'/>
 <input id='search_button' name='' title='Search' type='submit' value=''/>
</form>
```

**Result:**

> www.my_blog.blogspot.com/search?q=SearchText

**But i need search with this parameters:**

> www.my_blog.blogspot.com/search?q=label:Printers+SearchText

How i can do that, without javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest (if you don't want to use JS to handle query concatenations) to create multiple query properties using a **hidden input**:

> www.my_site.com/search?**category=Printers**&**q=SearchText**

```
<form action='/search' class='search' method='GET'>
    <input name='category' value='Printers' type='hidden'>
    <input name='q' placeholder='Пошук' type='text'>
    <input id='search_button' name='' title='Search' type='submit'>
</form>
```

Hm, *if* you really, **really** need one single and dynamically joined (prefixed) query param value like:

> www.my_site.com/search?**q=Category:Printers+SearchText**

such can be achieved by adding a bit of JS (I'll use the omnipresent jQuery library for simplicity sake)

```
$('form.search').on('submit', function (e) {

  // Prevent default form submit
  // since we need to cunstruct a prefixed param value
  e.preventDefault(); 

  // Set prefix and get SearchText
  var pfx = "Category:Printers+";
  var val = $(this).find('[name=q]').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: this.getAttribute("action"),
    data: { q : pfx + val }   // Join prefix to value into "q" param
  }).done(function(res) {
     console.log(res); // Success
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. but between **category** and **printers** must be ":" not "=".

Comment: @GUIMish OK, added an example that uses JS to create your **nonstandard** queryParam.

Comment: @GUIMish you're forgetting that HTML is static. A query param **property** is the actual field ***name***, and the value is the field's ***value***. You want to instead magically **prefix** the value. Use Javascript

Comment: Thank you. O.K. I weel be use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
function onSubmit(obj){
  var searchText = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var actionUrl = "/search?q=Category:Printers+"+searchText;
  console.log(actionUrl);
  obj.form.action=actionUrl;
  obj.form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form action='' class='search' method='GET'>
 <input name='q' id="text" idplaceholder='Пошук' type='text'/>
 <input id='search_button' id="search" name='' title='Search' onclick="onSubmit(this)"; type='button' value=''/>
</form>
```

Comment: Τhank you very much. But it is possible to do this without javascript?

Comment: Then what @Roko has suggested would be good.https://stackoverflow.com/a/51611450/3465242